# Messed up resolution when exporting screens with multiple scale in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png

this would be my first post.

When exporting to png files, resolution `Screen (72 ppi)` is the default selection when you select `Export As...` or `Save for Web (Legacy)...`. However in `Export for Screens...`, multiplying the scale will not only affect dimension but also its resolution.

For example, if I have 24x24 image with requested scale 1x and 2x. The result is:

- 24x24 (72 ppi)
- 48x48 (144 ppi)

I'm pretty sure this is not the desired goal. Those images with bigger scale are still intended for screen and not for print, therefore should stay on 72 ppi. Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Why is having metadata that is not used a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these images are for the web or on-screen viewing, then you don't need to worry, because web browsers and image viewing apps totally ignore the PPI setting.

An image 48px x 48px is exactly the same resolution no matter what the PPI is set to. PPI/DPI is an output resolution used in print. It's not the image resolution.

The only time PPI really matters is when you are scanning a document, or doing page layout for print. DTP applications use the PPI to set the size of the image on a page.

If you don't understand why, then read this: [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html)

Comment: But, and correct me if I'm wrong here, those excessive PPI will result in bigger file size, which usually matter in web or other digital media.

Comment: @HendraAnggrian - please read the article I linked to in my answer. It explains everything.